# How can I create a task function can delay and output in different order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Define a task function and the output after execution is as follows

```
task('james') 
// james starts work
task('james').waitFirst(5).do('push') 
// wait 5s, james do push, james starts work
task('james').wait(5).do('commit') 
// james starts work, wait 5s, james do commit
```

I have no idea how to create such a wait function, does anyone can help me about that or give me some ideas.

Comment: "chain methods with a wait function javascript" might be a good search to start looking at other questions

Comment: Do you have to do it only this way? The problem is `task(...).waitFirst(...)`. In this case we've to know that we are chaining `waitFirst()` to print the message `"james starts work"` later. How on Earth the `task()` function would know that: __Ok, there is no chained method call so lemme print `"james starts work"`???__

Comment: @h-sifat This is why I ask this quesion here, this problem is an interview question,The interviewer only prompted me that I could use promise to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with a little annoying `.end()` call after every `task()` call.

```js
function task(name) {
  const register = {};

  const preventCallAfter = (methodName) => {
    if (methodName in register)
      throw new Error(`You cannot use "wait" and "waitFirst" together.`);
  };

  return {
    wait(seconds) {
      preventCallAfter("waitFirst");
      register.wait = seconds;
      return this;
    },
    waitFirst(seconds) {
      preventCallAfter("wait");
      register.waitFirst = seconds;
      return this;
    },
    do(workName) {
      if ("workName" in register)
        throw new Error(`The .do() method is already called.`);

      register.workName = workName;
      return this;
    },
    end() {
      if ("wait" in register) {
        console.log(`${name} starts work.`);
        console.log(`wait ${register.wait} seconds.`);
        setTimeout(
          () => console.log(`${name} do ${register.workName}`),
          register.wait * 1000
        );
      } else if ("waitFirst" in register) {
        console.log(`wait ${register.waitFirst} seconds.`);

        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(`${name} do ${register.workName}`);
          console.log(`${name} starts work.`);
        }, register.waitFirst * 1000);
      } else console.log(`${name} starts work.`);
    },
  };
}

// task("james").end();
// james starts work
// task("james").waitFirst(5).do("push").end();
// wait 5s, chenlee do push, james starts work
task("james").wait(5).do("commit").end();
// james starts work, wait 5s, james do commit
```